# Resources about 2D in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I need some recommendations about drawing in Silverlight. Books are preferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take a look on this project:

http://livegeometry.codeplex.com/

It's one of the best examples of drawing in Silverlight.